# Swift: How do I use String.Index to work with replaceSubrange

Tags: swift

I can't figure out String.Index vs. Int

error is...

> Instance method 'replaceSubrange(_:with:)' requires the types
> 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent

```
func MID( destin: String, start_pos: Int, length: Int, source: String )
{
    var destin_string = destin
    let dest_index = Int( start_pos - 1 )
    let dest_end_index = Int( dest_index + length )
    destin_string.replaceSubrange(  dest_index...dest_end_index,    <<<<<< error
                                    with: source )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The index type of `String` is not `Int`-compatible because a character can contain multiple bytes.

A *workaround* to convert `Int` indices to `String.Index` is `NSRange` which matches the `startPos` and `length` parameters and which can be reliably converted to `Range<String.Index>`.

By the way to modify the string inside the function and never use it makes no sense. A better way is an `inout` parameter

```
func MID(destin: inout String, startPos: Int, length: Int, source: String )
{
    let nsRange = NSRange(location: startPos, length: length)
    guard let range = Range(nsRange, in: destin) else { return }
    destin.replaceSubrange(range, with: source)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to work with indices all the way and specially the function `index(:offsetBy:)`

Something like this

```
func MID(destin: String, start_pos: Int, length: Int, source: String ) -> String {
    var destin_string = destin
    let dest_index = destin.index(destin.startIndex, offsetBy: start_pos)
    let dest_end_index = destin.index(destin.startIndex, offsetBy: start_pos + length)
    destin_string.replaceSubrange(  dest_index...dest_end_index,
                                    with: source )

    return destin_string
}
```

You might need to adjust some calculations depending on what this function is supposed to do.

Here is a variant of the above with what I consider a bit better naming and some basic error handling

```
func replace(in string: String, start: Int, length: Int, with replacement: String ) -> String {
    if string.isEmpty || start >= string.count { return string }
    var input = string
    let startIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: start)
    var endIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: start + length)
    if endIndex >= string.endIndex { endIndex = string.endIndex }
    input.replaceSubrange(startIndex..<endIndex, with: replacement)

    return input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift `String` is a collection with its own `Index` type, which doesn't coincide with `Int` type as per Swift's `Array` collection.

You'd better read the the official `String` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) at the section "Manipulating Indices".

Anyway, in your case rather than that method you wrote, you'd better just write an helper in an extension to get the range of indices from a `String` instance and then use directly the `replaceSubrange(_:with:)` method.

Something like:

```
extension String {
    func indicesRange(position: Int, length: Int) -> Range<String.Index>? {
          assert(position >= 0 && length >= 0, "position and length must not be negative.")
          guard 
              let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: position, limitedBy: endIndex),
              start < endIndex,
              let end = index(start, offsetBy: length, limitedBy: endIndex),
              end > start
          else { return nil }
          
          return start..<end
    }

}

// usage assuming previously defined destination and source strings, 
// as well as startPos and length non-negative Int values:
if let range = destination.indicesRange(position: startPos, length: length) {
     destination.replaceSubrange(range, with: source)
}
```